# Looking for good bood suggestion relate dsp and antenna thoery

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis

I am a new student in dsp field and looking for a good book to practice at home.

Please provide good books.

Thank you.

Comment: Antenna theory is not really signal processing either...